# "Compiling" a HTML document

Tags: automation, html

To build a single application out of source code split in multiple files for organisation, one would use tools such as `make`.

So let's say you want to do the same, but for a HTML document. Maybe you have a long manual that's a hassle to edit all at once, so you split it in parts surrounded by `<article>` or `<section>` tags. And it'd be nice to add a table of contents on top out of the `h1` elements.

How would you go about doing that? Is there some standard tool built for it? Can you pull it off with `make`? Or would you write, say, a python script to do the parsing and compilation for you?

I realise there are different markup languages (such as TeX, which I already know) with such features available, but after reading about the more formal / semantic purposes of HTML5 in particular, it strikes me as a markup language well-suited for such "compilation" processes, but I can't name any tool that could pull it off (save for writing your own scripts).

Comment: `make` is just a scripting engine. And I believe what you're trying to do is called *text file concatenation*.

Comment: If I were doing this with static content, I'd write it in LaTeX and render it to HTML. If I were doing this with dynamic content, then use a javascript HTML templating engine and backend server programming language of your choice.

Comment: Templating sounds like an interesting solution.